# Carbonate reef not horizontal in seismic section?

Tags: geophysics, geology, seismology, carbonate

Carbonate reefs usually appear as homogeneous bodies surrounded by sediment layers in seismic reflection data, but in the figure below the high amplitude reflection from the top of sediment (layer 2  at 0.3-0.34 seconds) is not horizontal yet the geological interface is horizontal.

Can anyone explain why? I appreciate any input, thanks.
[image: Seismic profiles]

Answer (score 12):

This phenomenom is called **[velocity pull-up](http://www.glossary.oilfield.slb.com/en/Terms/p/pull_up.aspx).** The seismic waves that reflected off the top of Layer 2 beneath the carbonate layer have also travelled through the carbonate. Because carbonate (at least in this case) has a faster P-velocity than the surrounding shale, waves that have travelled through the carbonate will return to the surface receivers in a shorter amount of time, relative to waves that only travelled through the shale. Thus the carbonate/Layer 2 interface appears at an earlier two-way-time relative to the Layer 3/Layer 2 shale interface.

Comment: Cheers for adding link, kwinkunks.